# Saudi-Israel relations a reality? What are its potential effects?

Tags: israel, middle-east, saudi-arabia

There seems to be gathering rumours of an under-the-table, non-official alliance between Israel and Saudi Arabia. Both fear the rise of Iran and Hizbulla and it would be logical that they work together however weird that sounds.

What are the chances that such a relationship is being formed and that Israeli intelligence would share classified information with Sunni superpowers and vice versa? If it is true, how will this reorientation impact the Middle East? What will the effects of this new political power balance be?

Comment: VTC as needing secret sources, though asking for opinion (predictions) was a close second.

Comment: Actually [this was reported by reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-israel-saudi/israeli-minister-reveals-covert-contacts-with-saudi-arabia-idUSKBN1DJ0S1) a few days ago. The admission was from the Israeli Energy Minister. The Saudis seem to deny the collaboration (although there are special circumstances for them to do so).